# C++ : Allocate a big variable-sized 2d-vector on the heap

Tags: c++, vector, stack-overflow, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

(If my question is stupid,it is because i am a student)

In my program when i declare my big vector i get "stack overflow"

```
   cin >> big_number;
   vector<int> my_vector[big_number];
```

** stack-overflow** ...
(*note*: in the example above the big_number can take values up to 1.000.000)

In my understanding,this happens because variable-sized vectors are placed on the stack (instead of the default heap).

How can i put this 2d vector on the heap? 
Is putting the user-defined vector on the heap a "bad practice'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `vector<vector<int>>`

Code would look like

```
std::cin >> big_number;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_vector(big_number);
```

This will create a `vector` containing `big_number` of empty `vector<int>`